# Image bounds not rect but custom

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, frame

I want to add an image onto another image. But I know that imageview has a rectangular frame. Is there a way I can add an image without rect farme? Say, I want to add a pin onto an imageview. will it necessarily be a rectangular shaped imageview or can I add an image with frame shape that of a pin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is rectangular you can not add imgeView with other shape.

What you need is an transparent png that is your pin and added it to your original image view like an sub view.